# Read variable from a shell script in config file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I have a shell script in which i have defined some variables like

```
Shell script.sh xyz /abc/def/cde

usecase=${1}
CONFIGDIR=${2}
```

And I have a config file in which i want to take these variables

```
config file

USECASE=${usecase}
CONFIG=${CONFIGDIR}
```

Can you help me how to take the variable from the shell script to config file. I am thinking to use "source" command. I am not sure if that help. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: This seems backwards; usually, you use a configuration file to provide values to a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with given commands in shell script

```
usecase=${1}
CONFIGDIR=${2}
key1="USECASE="
key2="CONFIG="
echo $key1$usecase >> /path/to/your/config/file
echo $key2$CONFIGDIR >> /path/to/your/config/file
```

Make sure to replace "/path/to/your/config/file" with path of your config file